# Is there a REST endpoint to kick off a Bamboo build?

Tags: rest, continuous-integration, bamboo

I am trying to see how I might use `wget` or `curl` to kick off a Bamboo plan's build. I looked at their [REST API docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOODEV/Bamboo+REST+Resources#BambooRESTResources-BuildService-SpecificPlan) and it doesn't seem to be an exposed endpoint. Is this possible or does Bamboo discourage REST-based builds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. POST to the build queue service: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bamboo/bamboo-rest-resources/#BambooRESTResources-BuildQueueService

Answer (score 2):

You may use curl to trigger a build like below:

```
curl -X POST --user admin:admin http://host:8085/rest/api/latest/queue/PLAN-KEY?os_authType=basic
```